# i don't understand why list in object is shared with other objects

Tags: python-2.7

I make test python 2.7 code like below.

```
class test(object):
    #initial 5*5 array with 1
    value = [[1 for col in range(5)] for row in range(5)]

    def __init__(self, name) :
        self.name = name

test_list = [test("TEST"), test("test")]
test_list[0].value[0][0] = 0

print test_list[0].value[0][0]
print test_list[1].value[0][0]
```

What I expect is result like this

> 0
>   1

But Actual result is like

> 0 0

So it look like object "TEST" and "test" are sharing list.

If I change that code as below, then this problem doesn't appear.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, name) :
        self.value = [[1 for col in range(5)] for row in range(5)]
        self.name = name

test_list = [test("TEST"), test("test")]
test_list[0].value[0][0] = 0

print test_list[0].value[0][0]
print test_list[1].value[0][0]
```

I want to know why this two codes work different.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you've made `value` a class variable, so it belongs to the actual class and is shared among all instances of the class. In the second example, `value` belongs to instances of the class, and a separate copy of `value` is made for each instance.

Comment: class test(object):
    value = 0
    def __init__(self, name) :
        
        self.name = name

test_list = [test("TEST"), test("test")]
test_list[0].value = 1

print test_list[0].value
print test_list[1].value

If i make this code, then it works find. That problem doesn't occur with single variable, but with list or dictionary it occurs.